# Path expected for join generate in deploy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

```
        FROM Pers P
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Tel h with h.pers.id = p.id
        WHERE p.id = :id
```

Why deploy log generate this error
[ErrorCounter]   Path expected for join!

Comment: why is the join needed? if it is needed could you change it to FROM Pers p LEFT OUTER JOIN p.tel as h WHERE p.id = :id?

Answer (score 0):

The support for joins with entities i.e. ad-hoc or entity joins, was only introduced in Hibernate 5.1. I guess you are using an old version or maybe you enabled strict JPA compliance since JPA does not specify support for this.